# swap classes on click

Tags: jquery, class, list, swap

I have a list of 6 items that are in a global div (navigationagence)
Right now I am able to add a class on click but right now they adds up which means that once my six items are clicked they all end up with the currentagence class.

I want to be able to remove the add a class to the clicked item but remove it to the other, How can I achieve that? Here is the jquery code I am using right now.

$("#navigationagence ul li").click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("currentagence");
    });

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method to get the other list items and remove the class from them:

```
$("#navigationagence ul li").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("currentagence").siblings().removeClass("currentagence");
});
```

Comment: delegate would be better here

Comment: @redsquare, now I'm intrigued, can you provide an example? :)

Comment: well use .delegate to add one handler to the dom rather than x (in the OP's case 6). $('#navigationagence').delegate('li', 'click' fn);

Comment: @redsquare, got that, but it would only register the handler with a single element instead of six. It still wouldn't work with `toggleClass()` either, would it?

Comment: Yes it would - it uses event delegation to the container - any li click inside the #navigationagence will be bubbled to this handler.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use:

```
$("#navigationagence ul li").click(function() {
    $(".currentagence").removeClass("currentagence");
    $(this).addClass("currentagence");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Had to use Naveed solution because I forgot to mention that I had two ul list. both in a separate div and siblings does not work in this situation.